# EC2 instance storage performance degradation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it normal for EC2 instance storage disks to perform worse and worse over a few days? do they have IOPS quotas?

I launched a C5D.large instance a few days ago. Its job is to download a ZIP with 500 x 1mb text files (unzipped size), unzip them to disk and zip into 500 individual zips.

**TLDR**: it reads and writes files using the instance storage.

In synthetic tests it looked fishy:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/testfile bs=1G count=1

Day 1: 500MB/s 
Day 2: 120MB/s
Day 3 - 4: 40MB/s
```

Wasn't really an issue, because while working it had ~0 iowait and it was maxing out the CPU anyway:

[image]

The problem is that after 2 days of running it went to this:

[image]

The curious thing is that DD and HDPARM look okay?

```
# sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme1n1

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing cached reads:   15170 MB in  1.99 seconds = 7612.25 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 392 MB in  3.01 seconds = 130.24 MB/sec

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/testfile bs=1G count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 29.9148 s, 35.9 MB/s
```

---

Later edit: this is also happening on an EBS volume, with the difference that it doesn't recover after rebooting:

[image]

[image]

With an EBS, after launching or modifying the volume, it works great for a few hours, then the performance drops dramatically for the same workload.
Then it even struggles to sustain 50% of the initial throughput, to the point where I can barely log in and SU as root.

Comment: In the second image, you seem to have quite a bit of activity on the `nvme0n1` drive -- the root volume, which is EBS. Is your volume sized/provisioned sufficiently to support that level of activity? If not, it's where I'd look for your iowaits.

Comment: You could also try a TRIM (`sudo fstrim -v /mnt`) to see if that helps. If it does, run it on a regular basis using CRON.

Comment: @Parsifal it's a magnetic disk. It's probably just a coincidence, I don't write to that disk except when logging. Took a look now and there are plenty of moments when WAIT is huge without writing to that root disk.

Comment: I would be more worried about page faults, based on the difference between virtual and rss size for your main app. I'm afraid that I can't add any more other than "it should behave like any other attached disk," but you might find this useful: https://bencane.com/2012/08/06/troubleshooting-high-io-wait-in-linux/

Comment: @Parsifal thanks. I can see that it's just my process writing to the disk in question, but doesn't help much. If I log the iostat -x output over time, I will probably see requests/second increase more and more, because requests will take longer and longer? but essentially my process issues the same number of requests...

Comment: "I will probably see requests/second increase more and more" -- um, no: if requests take longer, you will have fewer of them per second (unless you have a pathological case of increasing threads or async io).

Comment: Got it, thanks. Everything about my process is the same over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like every EC2 instance type is capped at a certain bandwidth/IOPS when working with disks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html.